# How to Use OpenGL in android?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I want to draw circle ,rectangle etc in my application.
can any one suggest me how to use opengl in android?
and if any tutorial could u please share..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must create a custom `View` subclass, override its draw method and use an `OpenGLContext` to draw. See the [OpenGL topic](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html) in the Android documentation.

If you only need to draw some geometric primitives and performance is not a major concern (that is - you are making almost anything that is not a game), you will probably want to use the [`Drawable`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html) objects in `android.graphics` instead.